# Avoid Try n Catch when searching for XML nodes in XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is a method to check if some **specific nodes** exist or not in `XDocument` files.

Obviously based on some documents it may encounter some **NullExceptions**. (in line 5,6)

What way you recommend, how to change this piece of code to avoid using Try/Catch and not getting an exception?

```
            var xContents = xDocument.Root.Descendants("Content");
            if (xContents.Any())
            {
                doesIncludeThat =
                   xContents.Any(e => e.HasAttributes && e.Name == "Content"
                            && e.Attribute("Include").Value == @"Happy New Year");
             ...}}}
```

Comment: `(string)e.Attribute("Include") == @"Happy New Year"` will work. The `(string)` cast operator will return null if the attribute does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, will check it.

Comment: @KlausGütter You mean I use this: (string)e.Attribute("Include").Value == ... ?

Comment: No, without the ".Value". XAttribute has a set of cast operators to different data types.

Comment: Cause it gave the same error, now will remove the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `e.Attribute(name).Value` which will give a NullReferenceException if the attribute is not present, you can do one of these things which both will return null in this case:

```
e.Attribute(name)?.Value
```

or

```
(string)e.Attribute(name)
```

The latter makes use of one of the conversion (cast) operators defined in XAttribute, which also return null if the attribute does not exist.

Comment: Klaus, thanks for that, was something new for me, though not 100% sure if it be the best way for it and do I like it most or not, cause think of it as be a bit hacky, and maybe still many other approaches also can achieve the result, but it worked and I learned from it, +1 and marked it as the answer.

Comment: Oh you provided 2 approaches, the 1st one is also good. both are fine.